# Почему jquery mobile popup не работает если контент грузить програмно?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

Если скопировать просто в контект - все отлично работает, но если я гружу через jQuery .html то не работает, что я делаю не так?

Не работает: jsfiddle.net/nbnabw34

```js
$('#content').html('<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Actions...</a><div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li data-role="list-divider">Choose an action</li><li><a href="#">View details</a></li><li><a href="#">Edit</a></li><li><a href="#">Disable</a></li><li><a href="#">Delete</a></li></ul></div>');
```

```html
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content" id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Работает: jsfiddle.net/5oq47q8L

```html
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content" id="content"><a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">Actions...</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Choose an action</li>
        <li><a href="#">View details</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Disable</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, вместо ссылок на jsfiddle добавляйте код прямо в вопрос. Здесь есть собственный встроенный jsfiddle (нажмите Ctrl+M в редакторе).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю на сколько правильно, но предлагаю после вставки контента в `#content` вызвать на нем

```
$('#content').trigger('create');
```

Тест http://jsfiddle.net/6jo5t663/